# How to exchange information between objects?

Tags: python, instance

I have a class (my_class) which instantiate another class (xpto) and executes a method (connect); when this method finish it fires an event (on_connect) and i would like to know it in the 'my_class'. How can i do it ? - Thanks

```
class my_class():
    xpto = another_class()
    xpto.connect()
    ' if connection ok print a msg
    .....


class another_class()
    def connect():
        ....
        code follows and an event id fired is succeeded (on_connect)

    on_connect():
        ' here I would like to notify my_class the connection was ok and i do not know how to do it
```

I tried different approaches without success, most of the times receiving errors related with 'circular imports'.
Thanks

Comment: Could you add some of things you tried to your question? And clarify what you mean by notifying the other class?

Comment: Events make sense in asynchronously executing code. Is that the case here?

Comment: Additionally I'm not sure if this is possible because i don't have the full code. But maybe you could try instantiating the `my_class` in the global scope and using that inside `another_class`. If that doesn't help could you possibly include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need to put some effort into explaining precisely what it is you are trying to do, what you tried, and how it isn't working. As it stands, this is too vague and unclear to be useful for Stack Overflow. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to simply pass `my_class`' instance to the other class?

```
class my_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.xpto = another_class(self)
        self.xpto.connect()

    def on_connection_success(self):
        print("Connection succeeded.")

class another_class():
    def __init__(self, my_class_instance):
        self.my_class_instance = my_class_instance

    def connect(self):
        if connection_succeeded:
            self.on_connect()

    def on_connect(self):
        self.my_class_instance.on_connection_success()
```

Comment: Thanks Mayfair for your tip, it solved my problem